# Display posts in random post types

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

I am currently working in a project in wordpress.

Here i have to get all posts from two custom post types namely pt1, pt2.

But here i want to display posts with random post type(pt1, pt2).

Example)

I want to display first post from pt1, next from pt2 and again pt1 and next pt2 and so on...

How can i do this. Any help?
This is the code:

```
 $args = array(

'posts_per_page'   => 5,    

'orderby'          => 'post_date',

'order'            => 'DESC',   

'post_type'        => array('pt1', 'pt2'),  

'post_status'      => 'publish'

 ); 

$posts = get_posts( $args );

$num=1;

foreach($posts as $post) {

    if( $num % 2 == 0 )             

        echo $post->post_title.$post->post_type;

    else    

        echo $post->post_title.$post->post_type;

    $num++;

}
```

Comment: Is it for a main query? Please show the code you got so far?

Comment: birgire can u check the code and give ur idea?

Comment: What about `'orderby' => 'rand'` instead? But I don't follow your random criteria. You want to order by random post type but still have it in even/odd order.

Comment: ... or you want to feed the `get_posts()` with two random post types, and order the result by the even/odd pattern?

Comment: The functions `get_post_types()` and `rand()` might help you with the first part of selecting two random post types. But since you're ordering by post date, you might only get results from a single post type (e.g. p1)

Comment: can u explain some little bit code to display random post type's posts

Comment: But I think you should use two `get_posts()` call, one for each custom post type, and then use PHP code to loop through them to get the exact `p1, p2, p1, p2, ...` order you are seeking. To get two random post types you can try: `array_rand( get_post_types( $args ), 2 );`. You might need to filter the output with `$args`. See the Codex for more information on that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy query that will do that (see below). You will need to process your results in PHP to get the sort you are looking for. Something like this:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'   => 5,    
  'orderby'          => 'post_date',
  'order'            => 'DESC',   
  'post_type'        => array('post', 'book'),  
  'post_status'      => 'publish'
); 
$posts = get_posts( $args );

$even = $odd = array();
$ei = 0;
$oi = 1;
foreach ($posts as $p) {
  if ('post' == $p->post_type) {
    $odd[$oi] = $p;
    $oi = $oi + 2;
  } elseif ('book' == $p->post_type) {
    $even[$ei] = $p;
    $ei = $ei + 2;
  }
}
$posts = $odd + $even;
ksort($posts);
foreach($posts as $post) {     
  echo $post->post_title.$post->post_type;
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Obviously, I used post types that exist on my dev server, but swapping those out is trivial. The idea is the same.

The only way I know to make sure you get equal numbers of each post type in the query would be to create a `UNION`. I don't have the time write that now but [option 4 from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112612/21376) should get you started.

Comment: I guess we should also consider the case where the number of posts of post type `p1` is much greater than posts of `p2`. So I suggested using two `get_posts()` to ensure we get enough posts of each post type. Maybe you know of other way around that?

Comment: Yes, that is an issue. The code above will interlace the two, so long as there are enough results in the query. With some effort you can cause `WP_Query` to use a `UNION`. I have an answer I should look up showing how. For the record, your suggestion was the first thing that came to mind, but I didn't want to steal it :)

Comment: Good idea to try `UNION`. Our initial idea might not scale well using `n x get_posts()` calls for `n` post types, but I guess the normal use case would be for low values of `n`  ;-)

Comment: @birgire : see the edit. I found one of my answers involving a `UNION`.

Comment: ok, thanks for the link. Hopefully the OP has now enough information to solve his problem. +1