# display post types alternately

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

Is there a way to sort post types alternately.
So when you query two (or more, but let's take two for example) post types, is there a parameter or method wich you can use to display the results alternatly.
so like this

1. post type 1 (last post from post type 1)
2. post type 2 (last post from post type 2)
3. post type 1 (forlast post from post type 1)
4. post type 2 (forlast post from post type 2)

In de codex I can find nothing about this and it also seems that it is not a very common thing to do, because I can not find anything about it on the internet..

Comment: what do you mean by `forlast`??

Comment: I think it is all about using two Wp_Query's and embedding them in some loop(for or while). Have you tried something like this?

Comment: @Maritu Mohanty:  I mean the post posted before the last one

Comment: I thought about it, but have no idea how to do this, because when I make diffrent query's I have to give up diffrent order-by parameters, and i dont know how to loop the forlast post than

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display posts in random post types](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129558/display-posts-in-random-post-types)

Comment: Yes thank you that is what I want, I'm gonna try your answer over there on my posts2posts loop (yup, only connected post types), if that won't work I will try the UNION solution