# Retrieving 3 latest post from each of 5 different custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, query-posts, get-posts

I have 5 different custom post types. I am showing 15 latest post from them on my home page using following query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array (
             'posts_per_page'   => 15,
             'post_type' => array ( 'cpt1', 'cpt2', 'cpt3', 'cpt4', 'cpt5' ) 
          )
 );
```

It works fine, shows latest 15 posts from these 5 custom post types.
But problem is, there are too many updates on **cpt1** and **cpt3** (around 8-10 posts per day on each post type). So on home page, I rarely find posts from **cpt2/4/5**.

So I want to show latest 3 posts from each post type (total 15 posts) using date as order by (sorting). So 3 posts from each post type will be visible and sorted based on date among all 5 post types. But I could not find any good solution for this.

What came so far in my mind is, running 5 queries and saving them to an array, and then sort them.

Is there anyway I can do this using only one query, instead of 5 queries?

Comment: when you mean one query - are you trying to do this with WP_Query out of the box or are you fine with custom SQL?

Comment: Just do multiple queries, WP querying doesn't handle such type of logic.

Comment: @codearachnid custom query will also be ok, as long as it does not take much server load.

Comment: I have written several related answers, the most relevant is probably [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/112582/21376) which includes links to a couple of others.

Comment: @Rarst yes, I couldn't find any option with WP query. I can do this with 5 WP queries, but I am concerned about the performance, since it will take quiet much load.

Comment: @s_ha_dum thanks. I will try out with your codes to customize my query.

Comment: I don't have time to cook up working code but try to make the code from that link work, then paste in your attempt. I may have time to revisit later. Use the `UNION`. If you get that working it should be the most efficient option.

Comment: @rarst is there any performance difference in runnign 5 queries via wp_query versus a sql query?

Comment: @StephenS. yes, however quite often it's not meaningful enough to waste time on hammering out (nearly) completely custom querying code

Comment: @s_ha_dum I have done it with 5 queries using `Transient API`. I have added my code as an answer. Could you please have a look to see if this is a good solution? However, I am not facing any problem with this code, and contents loading pretty fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, if this is the most efficient option or not, but I have doen it in following way:

1. I have stored 5 separate query using `get_posts` and stored them in a single array
2. I had to flatten the array, since it was multidimensional. Then used `usort` using `post_date` to get the latest post
3. I have saved this sorted data using [Transient API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), to minimize database call.

Here is the code:

```
function delete_front_page_query_results() {
    delete_transient('post_data');

    $query_cpt1 = array (
            'posts_per_page'   => 3,
            'post_type' => 'cpt1'
            );
    $query_cpt2 = array (
            'posts_per_page'   => 3,
            'post_type' => 'cpt2'
            );
    $query_cpt3 = array (
            'posts_per_page'   => 3,
            'post_type' => 'cpt3'
            );
    $query_cpt4 = array (
            'posts_per_page'   => 3,
            'post_type' => 'cpt4'
            );
    $query_cpt5 = array (
            'posts_per_page'   => 3,
            'post_type' => 'cpt5'
            );

    $query_results[] = get_posts($query_cpt1);
    $query_results[] = get_posts($query_cpt2);
    $query_results[] = get_posts($query_cpt3);
    $query_results[] = get_posts($query_cpt4);
    $query_results[] = get_posts($query_cpt5);

    //flattening three dimentional array to two dimensonal array
    $flatten_array =array();
    foreach ($query_results as $data) {
            foreach($data as $flatten_data) {
                 $flatten_array[] = $flatten_data;
            }
    }

    function cpt_array_sort($a, $b) {
            return strtotime($b->post_date) - strtotime($a->post_date);
    }
    usort($flatten_array, 'cpt_array_sort');

    //setting transient with the array
    set_transient ( 'post_data', $flatten_array, 365*24*60*60);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'delete_front_page_query_results);
```

Comment: +1 for the use of transient and updating on save_post, i was looking for something like that to improve performance. n1

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in a single query. You must separate it out into multiple queries as SQL commands are not built to handle this type of processing, and thus neither is WordPress's Query API.

Comment: It's certainly possible in a single query with raw SQL, via [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Comment: And I provided a link, in comments to the question,  that demonstrates how to do it with `WP_Query`. It absolutely is possible in a single query if you are good enough with filters and SQL.